# Indexing a single-use temporary table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing, temp-tables

A colleague works in a business which uses Microsoft SQL Server. Their team creates stored procedures that are executed daily to create data extracts. The underlying tables are huge (some have billions of rows), so most stored procedures are designed such that first they extract only the relevant rows of these huge tables into temporary tables, and then the temp tables are joined with each other and with other smaller tables to create a final extract. Something similar to this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
INTO #TABLE1
FROM HUGETABLE1
WHERE COL4 IN ('foo', 'bar');

SELECT COL1, COL102, COL103
INTO #TABLE2
FROM HUGETABLE2
WHERE COL14 = 'blah';

SELECT COL1, COL103, COL306
FROM #TABLE1 AS T1
JOIN #TABLE2 AS T2
ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
LEFT JOIN SMALLTABLE AS ST
ON T1.COL3 = ST.COL3
ORDER BY T1.COL1;
```

Generally, the temporary tables are not modified after their creation (so no subsequent ALTER, UPDATE or INSERT operations). For the purpose of this discussion, let's assume the temporary tables are only used once later on (so only one SELECT query would rely on them).

Here is the question: is it a good idea to index these temporary tables after they are created and before they are used in the subsequent query?

My colleague believes that creating an index will make the join and the sort operations faster. I believe, however, that the total time will be larger, because index creation takes time. In other words, I assume that except for edge cases (like a temporary table which itself is extremely large, or the final SELECT query is very complex), SQL Server will use the statistics it has on the temporary tables to optimize the final query, and in doing so it will effectively index the temp tables as it sees fit.

In other words, I am used to think that creating an index is only useful if you know that table is used often; a single-use temporary table that is dropped once the stored procedure is complete is not worth indexing.

Neither of us knows enough about SQL Server optimizer to know in what ways we are right or wrong. Can you please help us better understand which of our assumptions are closer to truth?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: It depends. You'll have to measure it, but numerous times I've seen SELECT performance gain be 10x index creation time.

Comment: Further, sometimes it's a much better idea to simplty index the original tables properly rather than performing all these manual activities moving data around staging tables. Properly indexing and partitioning tables means that sql server can find the records much quicker and you don't need to write a bunch of table juggling code

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is probably correct, because even if a table's going to be used in a single query, without seeing the query (and even if we do, we still don't have a great idea of what it's execution plan looks like) we have no idea how many times SQL Server will need to find data within various columns of each of those tables for joins, sorts, etc.

However, we'll never know for sure until it's actually done both ways and the results measured and compared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing daily data extracts with billions of rows, I would recommend you use a staging tables instead of a temporary table. This will isolate your extracts from other resources using tempdb.

> Here is the question: is it a good idea to index these temporary tables after they are created and before they are used in the subsequent query?

***Create the index after loading the data into temp table.*** This will eliminate fragmentation and statistics will be created.

the optimizer will use statistics to generate the optimal plan. So if you don't have a statistics, it could dramatically affect your query performance especially for large datasets.

Example below query the before and after comparison of index creation in temp table:

```
/* Create index after data load into temp table -- stats is created */
CREATE TABLE #temp ( [text] varchar(50), [num] int);
INSERT INTO #temp([text], [num]) VALUES ('aaa', 1), ('bbb', 2) , ('ccc',3);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_num] ON #temp (num);
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('tempdb..#temp', 'IX_num');

/* Create index before data load into temp table -- stats is not created */
CREATE TABLE #temp_nostats ( [text] varchar(50), [num] int);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_num] ON #temp_nostats (num);
INSERT INTO #temp_nostats([text], [num]) VALUES ('aaa', 1), ('bbb', 2) , ('ccc',3);
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('tempdb..#temp_nostats', 'IX_num');
```

You need to test if the index will help you or not. You need to balance how many index you can have because it can also impact your performance if you have too many index.

Comment: Thanks dco, but you answered a different question: should an index be created before or after the data is loaded. Here, the question is should an index be created at all. In other words, if we don't create an index, doesn't SQL Server first go collect some stats as a first step of running the final SELECT query anyway?

Comment: @Merik **IT DEPENDS. You need to test if the index will help you or not**. if you dont have index on your table, SQL Server will scan the entire table.  The optimizer depends on the statistics to calculate the estimate cost "cardinality" of your table or index.

Comment: But if I do create an index, SQL Server will scan the entire table when it is creating the index, no? So that means the table scan cannot be avoided one way or the other.

Comment: Can you provide some links to support that? To the extent that I understand indexing, it is impossible to create an index without scanning all the data once.

Comment: @Merik I've overlooked the execution plan last time. it scans the table when data exist. Your mileage may vary if you like to create index before or after temporary table creation. Most of the time I would create index last to generate stats (it helps the optimizer to generate optimal plan). As mentioned, you need to test if it helps you to create index or not.